# How to identify unique entries in ccda file?

Tags: ccd, hl7-cda, c-cda

Basically, if user uploads same c-cda document again or other documents containing same entries of like medications, vitals, allergies, surgeries, etc than I want to make sure they do not get duplicated in database and want to skip those from inserting again.

Answer (score 2):

Each entry inside an HL7 CDA could have an id attribute, which definition form HL7 V3 RIM is: 
*3.1.1.3
Act.id :: SET (0..N)
Definition:A unique identifier for the Act.*

Use it in order to uniquely identify you entries, and avoid duplicates.

This element is not mandatory, but if you are implementing C-CDA, this template for substance administration specifies that this element is mandatory, so you should ask document sender to inform it. Here is a substance administration example form C-CDA:

```
<substanceAdministration classCode="SBADM" moodCode="EVN">
<templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.16"/>
<id root="cdbd33f0-6cde-11db-9fe1-0800200c9a66"/>
<text>
<reference value="#med1/>
Proventil 0.09 MG/ACTUAT inhalant solution, 2 puffs QID PRN wheezing
</text>
<statusCode code="completed"/>
<effectiveTime xsi:type="IVL_TS">
<low value="20110301"/>
<high value="20120301"/>
</effectiveTime>
<effectiveTime xsi:type="PIVL_TS" institutionSpecified="true" operator="A">
<period value="6" unit="h"/>
</effectiveTime>
...
```

Martí
martipamies@vico.org

Comment: do you mean to use root attribute of id tag available in each entry tags to uniquely identify entries?

Comment: Also what to do in case id value is not present? This is real-time case happening with me. Value is not present and I'm unable to identify its uniqueness. It seems unreliable solution. Help me.

Comment: Yes, I mean to use root and either extension atributes of id element included in every entry in orther to identy them.

Comment: Review my edited answer where a sample substance administration for CCDA is included.

Comment: thanks for your help. I have many c-cda files in which I found many entries do not contain id tag or root or extension attribute. And if they do contain then in some cases values are not GUID. Anyway I've implemented the way rules says that id values must be there. But it would be great if I could identify all entries in unique.